# LZRW1 decompression in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I have a database with data packed with LZRW1 algorithm and I need to read this data in a C# application. Does anyone know if there is a ready implementation of the LZRW1 decompression for C#?

Answer (score 0):

I had a good look, I can't find any in C# or Java. I suspect it's a generational issue - that specific algorithm has been surpassed by ZIP etc and there was little reason to write the code in newer languages.

Below are some implementations in C++ and Pascal:

- http://www.ross.net/compression/lzrw1.html
- http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/14494/download.aspx